# Ado.net Entities + get table by T

Tags: c#, ado.net-entity-data-model

Is it posible to get a table to do queries on with Ado.net Entities?

In linq ou could do DataContext.GetTable.Where......

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387004.aspx

Here are a couple of snippets taken from the "Queries in LINQ to DataSet" page.

This:

```
// Fill the DataSet.
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
ds.Locale = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
FillDataSet(ds);

DataTable products = ds.Tables["Product"];

IEnumerable<DataRow> query =
    from product in products.AsEnumerable()
    select product;

Console.WriteLine("Product Names:");
foreach (DataRow p in query)
{
    Console.WriteLine(p.Field<string>("Name"));
}
```

And this:

```
// Fill the DataSet.
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
ds.Locale = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
FillDataSet(ds);

DataTable products = ds.Tables["Product"];

var query = products.AsEnumerable().
    Select(product => new
    {
        ProductName = product.Field<string>("Name"),
        ProductNumber = product.Field<string>("ProductNumber"),
        Price = product.Field<decimal>("ListPrice")
    });

Console.WriteLine("Product Info:");
foreach (var productInfo in query)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Product name: {0} Product number: {1} List price: ${2} ",
        productInfo.ProductName, productInfo.ProductNumber, productInfo.Price);
}
```